# Laravel 5.7 returns multiple array from angular json object

Tags: php, angular, laravel

My json passed from angular

```
{
address: "sample address",
gst_no: "asdfas2342asfsdf",
vendor_code: "12312as",
vendor_name: "asdfsdf3",
}
```

In Laravel
**api.php**

```
Route::post('createVendor' , 'VendorController@createVendor');
```

**VendorController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Services\VendorService;
use App\Http\Traits\ApiTrait;


class VendorController extends Controller
{
    use ApiTrait;
    protected $vendorService;
    public function __construct(VendorService $vendorService){
        $this->vendorService = $vendorService;
    }


    public function createVendor(Request $request){
            $all_data = $this->getData($request);
            return $this->vendorService->create_vendor($request);
    }
```

**ApiTrait.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

trait ApiTrait {
    public function getData($data){
        $post = Input::json()->all();
        print_r($post);
        if(!isset($post))
            $post = Input::all();
        return $post;
    }
}
```

printing post returns this array

```
Array
(
    [vendor_name] => asdfsdf3
    [vendor_code] => 12312as
    [gst_no] => asdfas2342asfsdf
    [address] => sample address,
)
Array
(
    [vendor_name] => asdfsdf3
    [vendor_code] => 12312as
    [gst_no] => asdfas2342asfsdf
    [address] => sample address,
)
```

- but i have passed single json data, i don't know why this is
  happening if anyone have faced this and do you have any solution.
- **I am trying to convert json object from angular to php associative
  array**
- if there is any good way to achieve this you can also explain me on
  that too
- **Even if i hard coded and inserted from postman means two records are
  inserting**
- **so problem is not from json, so where might be the issue does any one
  know ?**

Comment: instead of print_r($post); can you use dd($post); and show the out put here?

Comment: dd($post) doesn't returns anything

Comment: @SKG do you have any idea of converting json to associative array in laravel?

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: @SKG laravel 5.7

Comment: Can you add dd($data->all()) and check the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185319/discussion-between-skg-and-vijay-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue

**Issue was in middleware**

> **In cors middleware**
>
> **I have initiated request twice like this**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request = next($request);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type,X-Auth-Token,Authorization,Origin');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Once removed the first line everything worked as usual